# I have a windows 10 computer that has a brave browser that tries to access the camera by itself

Tags: windows, virus, eset

I was browsing the web with my windows 10 computer and my browser wich is Brave wanted to accces the camera, and my antivirus Eset notifies  me of this. Why  does this happen, this is the second time.

Comment: Windows 10 allows control of camera permissions by app: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/app-permissions-aea98a7c-b61a-1930-6ed0-47f0ed2ee15c . That said, you might have a malicious add-on installed.

Comment: “Why does this happen, this is the second time.” - All modern browser request permission to use your microphone and camera this isn’t unique to Brave